# grep function with multiple terms for a mixed word vector

Tags: r, function, shiny

```
TEST<- function(x){
test <- data1[grep(x, data1$REMARKS),]
test1 <- test%>%
group_by(date)%>%
summarise(tot = sum(TOTAL, na.rm = T))
y <- ggplot(test1, aes(date, tot)) + geom_point() + geom_line()
return(y)
}
```

This is a function I'm working...  The dataset has a vector with multiple words within it.  Essentially what I want to do is create a function (maybe in Shiny) where I can input multiple words, which will pull the rows from the vector for analysis.  Is this possible with grep function?  The above function works well but for one word.  Thanks.

Comment: yep.  That worked great.  Thank you.  Curious if you can help me understand the difference between creating a regex vector and this:

Comment: You need to put the `|` separated terms in round brackets `(FORKLIFT|HYDRAULIC)`. This means match any of `FORKLIFT` and `HYDRAULIC`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility is to build a regexp search expression, based on multiple words. Have a look a the following example:

```
# Sample words
words <- c("word1", "word2", "word3");

# Construct regexp expression from list of words
makeRegExpr <- function(words) {
    return(sprintf("(%s)",paste(words, collapse = "|")))
}
makeRegExpr(words);
#[1] "(word1|word2|word3)"
```

You could then use `makeRegExpr(words)` in your function to filter entries that match *any* of those words.

```
TEST <- function(words) {
    test <- data1[grep(makeRegExpr(words), data1$REMARKS), ]
    ...
}
```

Comment: You removed your comment just as I was typing my response. I've added a comment to your original question. PS. If this answers your question, please accept the answer to close the question.

Comment: It worked well.  Thank you.  I will close the question.  Thanks Maurits.

Comment: No worries. Glad to help.